# Nullary Intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could someone explain in **layman's** terms what this is saying?

[image]

It seems to me that it means "Find the pairs (x,y) that are real numbers and y = x^n where n is a natural number."

My confusion stems from the seemingly large amount of numbers this encompasses. For example

```
(2,4) n = 2
(2,8) n = 3
... 
(2,64) n = 6
```

It seems a bit verbose for an answer. Could someone correct my understanding of this question?

Comment: For which $x$ and $y$ is it true that $y=x^n$ for **all** positive integers $n$?

Comment: By the way, is $0\in\mathbb N$? We have no way of knowing unless you tell us, because it depends on what textbook you're using.

Comment: By the way I don't understand your title. What does "nullary" mean here?

Comment: Yes. It is a member. Lord Shark had the solution.

Comment: I thought that was what this was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's dissect this:

$R_1 = \{ (x,y) : y = x^1 \} =  \{ (x,y) : y = x \}  \\
R_2 = \{ (x,y) : y = x^2 \} \\ 
R_3 = \{ (x,y) : y = x^3 \}... $

Now, $\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} R_n = R_1 \cap R_2 \cap R_3 \cap ... = \\
\{ (x,y) : y = x \} \cap \{ (x,y) : y = x^2 \} \cap \{ (x,y) : y = x^3 \} \cap ... = \{ (x,y) : y = x^n, \text{for all } n \in \mathbb{N} \} $.

Namely, the set of all pairs (x,y) such that $y = x^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$